# Is it possible to login in Facebook login with Http Client in 2015?

Tags: facebook, authentication, httpclient

There are several similar questions asked through the years, but even those posted sooner are not completely relevant to what I'm going to ask. The rest don't have answers or promote the usage of deprecated code and methods. So I don't consider my question a duplicate.

I'm trying to login with my personal FB credentials using Apache HttpClient for full search options which are not part of the Graph API (for example search by email, etc). So I'm pretty much asking if this is possible? It seems that it was possible back in the time.

I've tried lots of things in my code, so I'll paste just a short version of what I'm doing. The problem is that I always get an error message stating that Cookies are required and are not enabled.

I'm using Apache httpclient 4.4.1. Please don't paste me some code that you haven't tested. Ideas are welcome. I first make a GET request to the login page to retrieve the cookies, but **no cookies are stored in the CookieStore** no matter what cookie policy I'm setting or even if I'm adding the same http context to both requests:

```
CookieStore getCookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
RequestConfig globalConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.DEFAULT)
            .build();
HttpClient getHttpClient = HttpClientBuilder
            .create()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(globalConfig)
            .setDefaultCookieStore(getCookieStore)
            .build();
BasicHttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, getCookieStore);

HttpGet getPageRequest = new HttpGet(FACEBOOK_LOGIN_URL);
getPageRequest.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
getPageRequest.setHeader("Host", FACEBOOK_DOMAIN_URL);
getPageRequest.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,**/ *//*;q=0.8");
getPageRequest.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
getPageRequest.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
getPageRequest.setHeader("Referer", FACEBOOK_LOGIN_URL);
getPageRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

getHttpClient.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);

// NO COOKIES HERE !!!
CookieStore postCookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    System.out.println("getCookieStore.getCookies().size(): " +   getCookieStore.getCookies().size());
getCookieStore.getCookies().forEach(postCookieStore::addCookie);

HttpClient postHttpClient = HttpClientBuilder
            .create()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(globalConfig)
            .setDefaultCookieStore(postCookieStore)
            .build();

HttpPost loginRequest = new HttpPost(FACEBOOK_LOGIN_URL);
List<NameValuePair> loginCredentials = new ArrayList<>();

Document loginPageDocument = Jsoup.parse(getPageEntityString);
Elements hiddenInputElements = loginPageDocument.select("input[type=hidden]");
for (Element element : hiddenInputElements) {
    String id = element.id();
    String value = element.val();
    loginCredentials.add(new BasicNameValuePair(id, value));
}

loginCredentials.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", EMAIL));
loginCredentials.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", PASS));

loginRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(loginCredentials));

loginRequest.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
loginRequest.setHeader("Host", FACEBOOK_DOMAIN_URL);
loginRequest.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
loginRequest.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
loginRequest.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
loginRequest.setHeader("Referer", FACEBOOK_LOGIN_URL);
loginRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

String loginEntityString = "";
try {
    HttpResponse loginResponse = postHttpClient.execute(loginRequest);
    HttpEntity loginEntity = loginResponse.getEntity();
    loginEntityString = EntityUtils.toString(loginEntity);
    EntityUtils.consume(loginEntity);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    System.err.println(t.getMessage());
} finally {
    loginRequest.releaseConnection();
}

System.out.println(loginEntityString);
```

Comment: That would effectively be scraping, and that is not allowed by Facebook ToS, unless you have their explicit prior written permission. And also the reason why they are actively taking measures to prevent what you are trying to do. Graph Search is supposed to be used _by users_ on their website or in their official apps; you are not supposed to make automated requests to it. API search (different thing altogether) is pretty limited in comparison, but that is a deliberate choice by Facebook.

Comment: @CBroe, I guess this is the issue behind it all, but from software perspective I'm curious what is the exact reason for Apache HttpClient not to be able to fetch cookies. Any ideas?

Comment: Again, Facebook tries to detect this kind of activity, so you would have to a match a “real” browser as closely as possible, when it comes to request headers etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'm probably going to try a little harder. But first I have to decide if the effort is really worth for my project.

Comment: Hi, Galya! I am also trying to log into Facebook programmatically. Have you succeeded?

Comment: @Peter, please review the answer I've added to my own question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Great to know that is still possible. Can you please elaborate on that? Do you have a working example to share?

Comment: @Peter, I've added a working example to my answer. Please vote if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible way that I found to login into Facebook programmatically is using Selenium which may not be the best way for every application, but it's going to work for me. This is a working example of login into Facebook and searching for a key phrase. It may not be valid in the near future if the website's HTML get's changed.

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.facebook.com/");

    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(YOUR_FACEBOOK_EMAIL);
    WebElement passInput = driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
    passInput.sendKeys(YOUR_FACEBOOK_PASS);
    passInput.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

    WebElement searchInput = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[aria-label='Search Facebook']"));
    searchInput.sendKeys("YOUR_SEARCH_PHRASE");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[aria-label='Search']")));

    WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[aria-label='Search']"));
    searchButton.click();
```

Comment: Yes, it works! I just had to set-up the Firefox Driver `File pathToBinary = new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
  FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
  FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
  FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary,firefoxProfile);` and to use the latest version `<dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.48.2</version>
    </dependency>`

Comment: Is there a way to stop the web browser from popping-up?

Comment: I still don't know of a such, but what I'm going to do is to make a queue of requests for browsing, thus reusing the browser window multiple times.